# "Class _PathPoint is implemented in both" error when using Xcode

Tags: xcode

Even if I just type `print("hello")` this happens.

I'm using Xcode version 13.3 I tried reinstalling Xcode but the same error still appeared

> objc[1288]: Class _PathPoint is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x10fb07338) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x12d9a8fe8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. objc[1288]: Class _PointQueue is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x10fb07310) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x12d9a9010). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: Is this causing an actual problem or are you just asking about the log message?

Comment: I think it cause problem when I use realm but not sure so I wnat to know if there is any solution

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691361), this can be considered log noise.

> This is not an error per se. Rather, it’s the Objective-C runtime telling you that:

> Two frameworks within your process implement the same class (well, in this case classes, namely _PathPoint and _PointQueue).

> The runtime will use one of them, choosing it in an unspecified way.
> This can be bad but in this case it’s not.

> Both of the implementations are coming from the system (well, the simulated system) and thus you’d expect them to be in sync and thus it doesn’t matter which one the runtime uses.
> So, in this specific case, these log messages are just log noise.

I know it feels weird to have it all the time, but is safe to ignore it until apple update something in the playground and corrects the issue.